# scrape json from viewsource page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm trying to scrape json that exists in a website source and use it in my own site.

Heres an example site:
view-source:http://www.viagogo.co.uk/Theatre-Tickets/Musicals/The-Lion-King/The-Lion-King-London-Tickets/E-1545516

If you look partway down there is a `var eventListings`

I would like to get all the code that exists in that var

So far all i have is this:

```
url = "http://www.viagogo.co.uk/Theatre-Tickets/Musicals/The-Lion-King/The-Lion-King-London-Tickets/E-1545516"
 doc = open(url).read
```

Any ideas how i can get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you have so far will (basically) function using `open-uri` from the [Ruby standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html).  As with any standard library module, `require 'open-uri'` at the top of the file in which you use it.

`Open::URI` treats it job as to give you the contents of the file.  If you are comfortable using tools to search the raw text for the particular contents you are looking for, that may be enough.  There are a few gems, though, that assume you are likely to get back HTML and to provide special support for finding HTML elements and inspecting their contents.  [This post](http://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-mechanize) uses [`mechanize`](https://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize) which in turn is built on top of [`nokogiri`](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri).  It is likely to be easier to write working code when using this library, but be aware that installing nokogiri may be difficult in your staging or production environment when making the decision to use it.

Comment: Hey there, I already use the nokogiri gem, I'm more looking for an answer to get pecifically the json :)

Comment: That's the only occurrence of JSON.parse in the page, so you can use a RegExp to capture the line contents and parse that JSON yourself.  You won't need nokogiri/mechanize for that.

Comment: How would i go about this? Sam